# R.java not found on Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio

We've got a strange behaviour in an Android project we inherited. The APK **builds without error** but the **IDE keeps complaining about missing R class** in imports.

We are using Android Studio 3.3. (wrong ! see edit at bottom)

After a little more digging, we found that the R.java file is actually generated but in `build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources` rather than the usual `build\generated\sources`.

Does anyone already got this ? Even better, does anyone know how to fix this ?

Thanks folks!

*Edit : I was actually using Android Studio 3.2…*

Comment: Did you create a root package in src directory?

Comment: Thanks for this fast response !
I'm not sure to understand what you mean but we've got src/main and src/flavorA (+ some others such as androidTest, etc.) and both contain classes with correct directory structure, I think

Comment: Can you show us the project structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, thanks for all your support !

After reading @Kingfisher Phuoc response, I finally found that it was an **incompatibility** between my **Android Studio 3.2** and using **Android gradle plugin 3.3**.

I **updated my Android Studio to match the plugin** and now it is **working** !

It looks like the way the R class is generated have been updated in the 3.3 version (source: [release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#behavior_changes), look for *"Faster R class generation for library projects"*)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I have to revert the version of android build tool:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' // use this version instead of 3.3.0
```

Comment: Also, check out my answer here for the next step,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178731/how-can-i-stop-android-studio-indexing-scanning-building-altogether-at-startup/51104279#51104279

Answer (score 3):

In my case R.java always generates in `build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources` . You can try cleaning and rebuilding the product.

Comment: True, this was actually a version conflict between my Android Studio and the Android Gradle plugin !