# R class is not found in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

in older versions of Android Studio, I used to be able to navigate to the java(generated) package and see the R class.

I am using Android studio 4.1 and I can't see R class in Java generated package.
any idea why is that?

and where I can find the R class?

P.S. I did rebuild the project
P.S.S. it's not causing any error.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R.java not found on Android Studio 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444917/r-java-not-found-on-android-studio-3-2)

Comment: I have already tried the answers there yet I can't see the R class.

Answer (score 1):

Steps you can try:

1. Clear cache and Restart.
2. Clean and Rebuild the project.

This should fix your issue.

Comment: tried those steps, still can't find it. p.s. it is not causing any error

Comment: This is android studio's cache issue problem. Sometimes it doesnt show the files and sometimes fails to find the references to the variables.

Comment: what version of android studio are you using? do you see R class under the generated java package?

Comment: You can find R class by searching it with "shift + cmd + o" or "double shift". Hope this will help.

Comment: This has been a plague in AS since the beginning.